# iAd doesn't fit width of screen

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, iad

I am trying to add an iAd to my iPad app, which only works in landscape. However, when the ad appears, it does not fit the width of landscape (it has the dimensions for portrait). I have set the autoresizing masks below, yet nothing happens. How do you get this to work?

```
[iAd setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use the autosizing without flexible, just the orientation mask? That might do it. Furthermore I have always placed the mask in the autorotation method, since iOS 6 I changed the I ad rotation to masks and it rotates and fits properly. Just an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ADBannerView` already exists in a XIB file and is linked using an `IBOutlet`. Even though the `ADBannerView` is extended in the XIB, it does not show this way on a device. Even setting up the autoresizing masks and using autolayout did nothing. So, I set the width of the frame of the iAd manually.

```
iAd.frame = CGRectMake(iAd.frame.origin.x, iAd.frame.origin.y, 1024, iAd.frame.size.height);
```